# Aws CloudSearch: How to use _score as a filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, search, filter, cloud

is there a way to use _score to filter the cloud search results? I am trying to refine the output in order to show only relevant results.

I wanted to do something like

(and  ( or ii_disponivel:1)(or range field=_score{10,}))

Answer (score 0):

Score is only on query not on filters. Also explore about function_score. That might help. I can’t comment more on function_score as I too haven’t used it yet.